# IIS rewrite rule not passing parameters

Tags: redirect, iis, url-parameters

I have redirects currently set up to go from oldsite.com to newsite.com using a rewrite map. They work except when a parameter is passed through the URL, ex. http://oldsite.com?utm_source=go.wayne.edu&utm_medium=direct&utm_campaign=quick-access&utm_content=, still goes to the old page instead of redirecting to the new page with the parameters, ex. http://newsite.com?utm_source=go.wayne.edu&utm_medium=direct&utm_campaign=quick-access&utm_content=.

Here's my code:

```
            <rule name="Redirects to New Site">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{RelaunchRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsite.com/{C:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

Still very new to all of this and I can't figure out why the parameters are not passing. I've seen some similar cases on here but haven't been able to get those solutions to work for me.

Any ideas on what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this URL Rewrite rule:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                 <rule name="Redirects to New Site" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newsite.com{URL}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

[image]

Feel free to let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very close to what I want to do, however, the updated code ignores the rewrite map with all of the redirects. How can I incorporate the rewrite into what you have here and achieve the same result?

Comment: You mean your code will invalidate the URL Rewrite Rule?

Comment: Thank you! No, I mean that the line `<add input="{RelaunchRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />` references are rewrite map that contains all of the redirects. If we remove that line, we will also remove the redirects list. The rewrite map is essentially a list of redirects from an old path to a new one. We want to keep that rewrite map in place but still have the parameters to append like in your solution. I just don't know how to combine the two methods.